# Set path for Terminator to lookup for plugins

Tags: plugins, terminator

In my work place we have `Terminator` installed on our machines but we do not have write access outside of our home folders. By default, terminator looks for pluings at `/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins`, which I cannot use. I tried to copy my plugin to `~/.config/terminator/plugins/` but terminator doesn't load anything from that location.

How can I tell terminator to look in that folder, as well as the default one? Perhaps some entry in the config file, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

#### Edit:

As was asked in the comments, here is the output of `apt-cache policy`"

```
terminator:
  Installed: 0.97-2ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 0.97-2ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.97-2ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.97-2 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy terminator`

Comment: @A.B., please check edited post.

Answer (score 2):

Check the opened files with

```
strace -e open,access terminator 2>&1  | grep plugins
```

If your folder isn't in the output, something is wrong. And you should read the man page

```
man terminator_config
```

But in the meantime you have recognized it themselves. **;)**

---

Terminator has two plugin folders. The system-wide folder `/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins` and an user folder `~/.config/terminator/plugins`.

I have tested the installation of plugins in the home folder with the plugin [Terminator Editor Plugin](https://github.com/mchelem/terminator-editor-plugin):

1. My `terminator` without this plugin

   [image]
2. Close all `terminator`  sessions
3. Create the plugin folder

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/terminator/plugins
   ```
4. Download the plugin

   ```
   wget -P ~/.config/terminator/plugins https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mchelem/terminator-editor-plugin/master/editor_plugin.py
   ```

   You should now see something like this

   ```
   % ls -laog ~/.config/terminator/plugins
   total 20
   drwxrwxr-x 2 4096 Nov 19 14:39 .
   drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Nov 19 14:27 ..
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 3438 Nov 19 14:39 editor_plugin.py
   ```
5. Start `terminator`
6. Check the content in `~/.config/terminator/plugins`, you should see something like this:

   ```
   % ls -laog ~/.config/terminator/plugins
   total 32
   drwxrwxr-x 2 4096 Nov 19 14:32 .
   drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Nov 19 14:27 ..
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 3438 Nov 19 14:32 editor_plugin.py
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 3811 Nov 19 14:32 editor_plugin.pyc
   ```
7. Open <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Plugins</kbd>
8. Activate the plugin <kbd>EditorPlugin</kbd>

   [image]

Comment: Before I post the question, I did exactly the same but the plugin doesn't appear in the preferences.  However, it doesn't create the `.pyc` file after I launch `terminator`.  As it was the point of my question, it somehow fails to check that directory. Fun fact: I was trying to install exactly the same plugin that you used as example.

Comment: Test this `~/.config/terminator/plugins; python -m py_compile editor_plugin.py`. Do you have now a `pyc` file?

Comment: Compiling it, I do have the `pyc` now. But still no new plugin in terminator.

Comment: Was only a test, you should remove the file. Terminator have to create the file.

Comment: Install tree: `sudo apt-get install tree` What's the output of `stat  ~/.config; tree -pu ~/.config/terminator; ` Use a pastebin service for the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I can tell you that there is only a plugins directory, with aforementioned python file in it. Only that (not even the config file).  Stat says that my last access, modify and change has been an hour ago.

Comment: And the ownership of the folders? That was the reason for the stat and the tree command

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think have full access: `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31807/discussion-between-a-b-and-pouya).

Comment: I found the problem. But thanks A LOT for your help. I learned a lot from these comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was explained in `man terminator_config`.

From `man man terminator_config`

```
Normally the config file will be ~/.config/terminator/config, but it may
be overridden with $XDG_CONFIG_HOME (in which case it will be
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/terminator/config)
```

It turned out in my machine the default location for config is not `$HOME/.config` but `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config`. Once I moved the plugin to that location, terminator immediately locate it.